# How to DELETE row in table if row already exists in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have seen various examples of delete row if a certain condition does not exist for another table.

I would like to delete row from a table if it already exists in another table. I came up with this query but it seems to be simple and I am worrying I am missing something.

```sql
DELETE FROM tmp t
WHERE (t.employee = (SELECT p.employee FROM position p
                         WHERE (t.column1 = p.column1 AND
                                t.column2 = p.column2)
                        )
      );
```

Comment: What are you concerned that you're missing? You could add a `LIMIT 1`  to limit deletion to a single row.

Answer (score 1):

That should be done using `EXISTS`. First, you don't run the danger of the subquery returning more than one row. Then, you can get a better execution plan.

```
DELETE FROM tmp
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FROM position
              WHERE (tmp.column1, tmp.column2, tmp.employee) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM
                    (position.column1, position.column2, position.employee)
             );
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What would happen if the subquery would return more than one row?

Comment: You'd get a runtime error, because that is not allowed in SQL. How should you compare a single value to a table?

Comment: this does not seem to work if a field contains NULL? NULL = NULL returns NULL rather than true.

Comment: Should I use IS NOT DISTINCT FROM everywhere where I use a column which can contain a NULL value in a comparison?

Comment: Yes, that is better. I didn't consider NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Postgres documents](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html), you can use the better structure to delete items

```
DELETE FROM [ ONLY ] table_name [ * ] [ [ AS ] alias ]
    [ USING from_item [, ...] ]
    [ WHERE condition | WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name ]
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

You can use the `USING` keyboard to join both tables.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=209436c0327108b11729f07a9227d530)

```sql
delete from tmp t
using position p
where 
  t.column1 = p.column1 
  and t.column2 = p.column2
  and t.employee = p.employee;
```